# How to get Google Search keywords used to find my website in PHP without Google analytics?

Tags: php, analytics, google-search-api

We are trying to develop an analytics section in our site ( built in PHP). And we want to capture the search words which are used to find our website in search engines ( like Google.com) while it is redirected to our site.

Let's take an example, our site is "designsolution.com" and some people search in google with "best web designing company in Kanpur" and google.com showing our site on the first page. Then the user clicks on our site link and googles redirects the user to our site. Now, we want to know that the "best web designing company in Kanpur" used to search and find us.

Is there any way to get Google Search Terms/keywords in PHP? Any API service or any custom code? Please help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to share my research here as I found many people also looking for it.

We can get Google Search keywords for our website using Google Webmaster console API

You need to sync or fetch data after Authorize Google Webmaster console API with your website.

**Here is Search google search console API:**

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/

**Here is the sample code:** https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/samples

**Another code library:**
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow community.

When you click on a link in Google search result and you get redirected to your website, all data that Google sends to your website is just the `Referer` header parameter. So it's impossible to actualy get the search term using only PHP code. You can just findout that user came from Google search result.

Instead, you have to use [Google webmasters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) and submit your website there so you can see what keywords used for finding your website.

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you for the info actually I had confusion and you make me clear about it. Thanks again. Cheers

Comment: @BRwebdesignsolution So if my answer helped you can click on the tick and accept it. Thanks :)